# Does it make sense to talk about the integral of measurable functions that are not absolutely integrable?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lebesgue-integral

Suppose $f$ is a real-valued (possibly infinite-valued) function on some measure space $(X, \Sigma, \mu)$, and suppose that it is measurable.  Note that $f$ is not necessarily nonnegative.

Does it make sense to talk about $\int \limits_{X} f(x) \,d\mu$ if $f \not \in L^{1}(d\mu)$ (i.e., $\int \limits_{X} |f| \,d\mu \not < \infty$)?

If this is true, I think this is a very subtle point.  I was always under the impression that any **measurable** function can be integrated, but now I doubt that this is true if the function is not nonnegative.

Comment: There is a nuscence about $\infty - \infty$ if I recall.

Comment: It makes sense to talk about this integral if at least one of the integrals over $f^+$ and $f^-$ is finite. Not if both are infinite.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One can define a meaningful integral as

$$
\int f \, d\mu = \int f_+ \, d\mu - \int f_- \, d\mu,
$$

As long as at least one of the two integrals on the right hand side is finite.

Here, $f_+ (x) = \max \{0, f(x)\}$ is the positive part of $f$ and the negative part is defined analogously.

Comment: Is there an alternate convention that suggests we only discuss $\int \limits_{X} f \,d\mu$ if *both* $\int \limits_{X} f_{+} \,d\mu$ and $\int \limits_{X} f_{-} \,d\mu$ are finite?  Or am I misunderstanding my notes?

Comment: These integrals are **both** finite iff $\int |f| d\mu <\infty$. In this case, $f$ is called integrable. A function for which only one of the two integrals is finite is often called **quasi**integrable. Usually, integrable functions are the more interesting objects, e.g. because the space of all integrable functions is complete.

Comment: Thank you for your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

This question is basically answered in comments, but one could remark that there
are ways to extend the integral beyond "quasi-integrable" functions (those for which at least one of $f_+$ or $f_-$ has finite integral).  Namely, improper integrals
give a way to do this.

Suppose that we write our measure space $X$ as the increasing union of subsets $A_n$,
often assumed to be of finite measure.  Then we can consider $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{A_n} f d\mu,$$
and if this exists, call it the improper integral of $f$.

A common case is when $X = [0,\infty)$ and $A_n = [0,n].$  Another
possibility (I think called the Cauchy principal value) is $X = [-1,1]$ (or some
other interval containing the origin) and $A_n = [-1,-1/n] \cup [1/n,1]$ (whose
union is not quite all of $X$ --- their union is $X \setminus \{0\}$ --- but has
full measure in $X$).

The theory of improper integrals is like the theory of conditionally convergent series --- it relies on cancellations to obtain a well-defined limit when the function is not absolutely integrable.   Of course not all functions have a well-defined improper integral either.  And in general the improper integral can depend on the choice of sets $A_n$.